# redirect_uri_mismatch when request an offline token from Google / Youtube OAuth API

Tags: google-oauth, .net-core, google-api-dotnet-client, youtube-data-api

- Language: C#
- Framework: .NET CORE 1.1.1
- Nuget: Google.Apis.YouTube.v3 1.25.0.760 and Google.Apis 1.25.0

Hi,

**What I try to do**

I need to get an access token (with a refresh token) to upload videos on my users YouTube accounts.

**What is not working**

When I request a token through Google API, it's working in localhost but not in production. In production I get `redirect_uri_mismatch` error when I redirect user to Google's OAuth server.

**How I try to do it**

I created a console token in Google API Console because I need to retrieve an offline token (it's not possible to get an offline token if I create an Web Application token on the Google API Console).

**In my code** : I redirect the user to Google's OAuth server with this url :

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=XXXXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=MyRedirectUri&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly&response_type=code&access_type=offline
```

To make things more easy to read :

- Base URL : https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth
- client_id : myclient ID
- redirect_uri : http://localhost:43443/Account/Oauth (dév) and http://xxxxxx.azurewebsites.net/Account/Oauth (prod)
- scope : https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly
- response_type :code
- access_type : offline

In development, it's working. In production, it's not working (`redirect_uri_mismatch`)

[image]

I also tried to change redirect_uri to `urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob` like [the answer of this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25127248/error-redirect-uri-mismatch-while-trying-to-get-access-token-using-oauth) said. But it's just open a page with a code to copy / paste.

**PS** : I notified that when I download my "client_secrets.json" from Google Console API, there is a `redirect_uris` in the download file which have these values : `["urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob","http://localhost"]`. But in the Google API Console I can't modify this parameter.

**PS2** : I don't use .NET API to request token because [as the answer to this post say](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25144667/using-the-youtube-v3-data-api-for-net-how-is-it-possible-to-get-a-refresh-toke) (and as I tried previously), getting an offline token with .NET API is not possible.

Thanks for your help

**EDIT 1 :** 
[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23717452/how-to-add-multiple-redirect-uris-for-google-oauth-2) not answer my question because he use a "Web application token" for one shot request. In my case, I use "Console token" (called "Other" in Google API Console) where I can't set the redirections. I use "Console token" to get an offline token.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add multiple redirect URIs for Google OAuth 2?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23717452/how-to-add-multiple-redirect-uris-for-google-oauth-2)

Comment: In the post you mentioned, he use a "Web application token" for one shot request.
In my case, I use "Console token" (called "Other" in Google API Console) where I can't set the redirections. I use "Console token" to get an offline token.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the dev console, you should be using "web application token", and that will allow you to specify `http://xxxxxx.azurewebsites.net/Account/Oauth` as one of your redirect URLs. Also note that using a plaintext URL is not encouraged, so ideally you should be serving `https://xxxxxx.azurewebsites.net/Account/Oauth`. In the dev console you can add multiple URLs, so I suggest add both the http and https versions.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. If I use a "web application token" I will not be able to get an offline_token. And I need an offline token to upload videos on my users account.

Comment: @JohnB yes you can get an offline refresh token from a "web application credential"

Comment: The last time I tried to get an offline token with a "web application credential" I get an error saying that I can't. I'm gonna try again. If there is an error I will update my post. Thanks

Comment: I just tried to get an offline token with "web application credential" and it works. I just have a problem when I try to refresh it, but it's not the same topic. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just add this

```
app.Use((context, next) =>
       {
        context.Request.Scheme = "https";
        return next();
       });
```

on your startup class (Startup.cs) under the "Configure" method.